# Установка чистого Linux на смартфон

Tags: linux

Доброго времени,
Интересует возможность установки на смарт Linux, без эмуляции в Андройде, именно чистая установка!
С телефона андроид сносим. взамен нужно поставить linux, желательно debian.

Linux нужно без проприетарных библиотек (Ubuntu Touch не подойдет). 
Гугление результатов особых не принесло, хотя много интересного почитал.

Возможно кто-нибудь пробовал/слышал как реализовать.
Любые Ваши советы будут крайне полезны.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67161/discussion-on-question-by-dead4nv---linux--).

Answer (score 1):

Подключаешься по adb и удаляй dalvik - будет чистый линукс, с которым можно работать дальше только по adb.

Нужно разблокировать раздел на запись, установить busybox, дальше можно вычищать всё что не нравится. Андроид - это набор библиотек, которые лежат обычными файлами.

Ядро перебирать смысла нет - потому что драйвера на железо смартфона обычно в свободном доступе не найти.

Насчет дебиана. Берете debootstrap и на компе собираете папку с нужными программами. Закачиваете в смарт на освобожденный раздел и выполняете там mount, switchroot, init. Linux андроида и bysybox поработают в качестве initramfs для Debian.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67160/discussion-on-answer-by-eri---linux--).

Answer (score 0):

Установка "чистого" gnu/linux возможно только на очень малое количество телефонов. Объединяет их только факт открытого кода загрузчика т.н. bootloader.

Но даже при том условии что бутлоадер будет открыт, установке "чистого" линукса может помешать факт того, что дайверов устройств телефона не найти в открытом доступе.

По теме вопроса, линукс можно накатить только на телефоны вроде этого: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Openmoko
А так же на все поделия, собранные на базе raspberry pi.

Comment: что еще за телефоны на распберри?

Comment: @Evgeniy Shubin, драйвера да, проблемно найти. поделия на распбери  не попадались)))

Comment: @koshkashoshka Рецепт простой, добавляешь gsm модуль, микрофон и динамик - и вуаля, получается что-то вроде: https://habrahabr.ru/post/221567/

Comment: @EvgeniyShubin Да ясно, что в теории можно и на разных STM32 и на Atmega328P (т.е. плата ардуино) даже) Но не встречал что-то ни в билайне, ни в евросети, ни сколько ремонтировал - нигде не было внутри распберри и т.п.)) Ибо нафига?